# making my image and script responsive

Tags: css, alignment

sorry if this has already been asked but i searched and couldn't find anything so hoped someone could help if ok.

I have made the script within the heart image, which is a countdown till i get married but I cant get it to resize on an iphone. I have tried aligning it but then it throws everything off and nothing lines up.. My question is.. is there anyway i can keep the script and the image together and line it up as a whole making it responsive?

I have added the html and css below, any help would be appreciated..

Many Thanks sorry for a newbie question.

```css
.countdown-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent url("../img/1/Heart.svg.png") no-repeat center center /contain;
}

#countdown {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: table;
}

#countdown p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Tangerine;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="heart-countdown" class="heart-countdown container">
  <div class="countdown-wrap">
    <div id="countdown">

      <script>
        <!--// script goes here -->
        today = new Date();

        target = new Date("August 10, 2018");
        msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        timeLeft = (target.getTime() - today.getTime());
        e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
        daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<p>There are only<br> <strong>" + daysLeft + " days </strong><br> until we are Mr and Mrs</p>";
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can simplify this a bit, I would suggest something like this:

```js
var today = new Date();
var target = new Date("August 10, 2018");
var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
var timeLeft = (target.getTime() - today.getTime());
var e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
var daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);

document.getElementById("countdown-output").innerHTML = daysLeft + ' days';
```

```css
html, body {

  height: 100%;
  
}

#countdown {
  
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5vw;
  
}

#countdown strong {
  
  display: block;

}

#countdown:after {
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 400px;
  content: '';
  height: 100vw;
  max-height: 400px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
  background-size: contain;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
  There are only
  <strong id="countdown-output">0</strong>
  until we are Mr and Mrs
</div>
```

There are no complicated containers here, theres just the text and an `after` element (where you can use the heart background, which I don't have here), which is highly simplified and now your text can move, resize, etc... and the background will just scale and move as desired. It even scales with page size. Important, though, for mobile, is to use a correct viewport tag so scaling will actually work as expected:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Thank you for that @somethinghere